# Spring send message to Websocket Message Broker

Tags: spring, jhipster, spring-websocket

I want to send a message to websocket subscribers of a specific record - when an action takes place in one of my service class.

I'm trying to read the [Spring Websocket documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html) but it's kind of ambiguous to the point of how to get all these things working together.

Here are my setup files (this is extending jHipster btw):

WebsocketConfiguration.java

```
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableStompBrokerRelay("/queue/", "/topic/", "/exchange/");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        config.setPathMatcher(new AntPathMatcher("."));
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws").withSockJS();
    }
```

WebsocketSecurity.java

```
@Override
protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {
    messages
        // message types other than MESSAGE and SUBSCRIBE
        .nullDestMatcher().authenticated()
        // matches any destination that starts with /rooms/
        .simpDestMatchers("/topic/tracker").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
         .simpDestMatchers("/topic/**").authenticated()
        // (i.e. cannot send messages directly to /topic/, /queue/)
        // (i.e. cannot subscribe to /topic/messages/* to get messages sent to
        // /topic/messages-user<id>)
         .simpTypeMatchers(SimpMessageType.MESSAGE, SimpMessageType.SUBSCRIBE).denyAll()
        // catch all
        .anyMessage().denyAll();
}
```

Controller class (attempt at implementing a simple broker I can test subscribing to from sockjs and recieving messages generated elsewhere in the application:

```
@MessageMapping("/ws")
@SendTo("/topic/sendactivity.{id}")
public void activity(@DestinationVariable string id, @Payload String message){
    log.debug("Sending command center: "+message);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/updateactivity", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ResponseEntity<Membership> updateMembership(
        @RequestBody Membership membership) throws URISyntaxException {
    // ...
    String testString = "test";
    messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/commandcenter"+membership.getId().toString(), testString);
    // ...
}
```

When I put a breakpoint on the `public void activity` method, I don't get anything?

Comment: Could you share the sockJS client logs? There's no way to see which message was sent and what response it got in return. Could you also put `org.springframework.web.socket` in DEBUG and share the relevant logs as well?

Comment: @BrianClozel - I haven't even subscribed to the channel yet - would that cause it not to be active?! I thought after I ran `convertAndSend` I should hit the breakpoint in the `void activity` method?

Answer (score 0):

Sending a message to `"/topic/commandcenterID"` using the messaging template will send that message to the message broker, which will dispatch that message to clients subscribed to that topic. So it won't flow through your activity method.

When using `@MessageMapping` annotated methods, you're declaring those as application destinations. So sending a message to `"/app/ws`" should map to that method. Note that in that case I doubt it'll work since the destination variable you're expecting as a method argument is missing from the path definition in the `@MessageMapping` annotation.
Also, the `@SendTo` annotation in fact tells Spring that the value returned by the method should be converted to a message and sent to the given destination.

It seems you're mixing things up here, and I think you should:

- read carefully the [flow of messages in Spring STOMP support](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-message-flow)
- look at a few example apps like the [websocket portfolio](https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio) and [websocket chat](https://github.com/salmar/spring-websocket-chat)